# Combinatorial assignment to "composite" wire in always block

Tags: system-verilog

This is not a blocker that I'm dealing with, just looking for possibly a more elegant way of doing it.

```
module Ram(RamClk, CKE, CAS, RAS, WE, DQM, BA, A, DQ,
           OpEnable, Addr, RdData, WrData, Ready);   
    input RamClk;
    output CKE;
    output logic CAS, RAS, WE;
    output [1:0] DQM;
    output logic [1:0] BA;
    output logic [11:0] A;
    inout [15:0] DQ;

    input OpEnable;
    output [23:0] Addr; //24 bits = 16 Mb
    output [15:0] RdData;
    input [15:0] WrData;
    output Ready;

    // code omitted here

    wire CMD = {CAS,RAS,WE};

    // code omitted here

    //multiplexers
    always @*
    begin
      if    (InitDone == 0)
        begin
           CMD = InitCmd;
           A = InitA;
           BA = InitBA;
        end
        else
        begin
           //todo: assign the output of the main CMD, A and BA multiplexers
           CMD = CMD_NOP;
           A = 0;
           BA = 0;
        end     
    end

    //rest of the module
```

I have 3 outputs of the module `RAS`, `CAS`, `WE` that I'm combining into a single wire for convenience so that I can assign command values to them as a whole.

Now I need to connect a multiplexer to `CMD` and I'm doing it in an always block for convenience.

I could do it in separate assign statements in this case of only 2 inputs to the multiplexer using the ternary expression, but let's imagine the multiplexer has more inputs, for more inputs it looks more convenient to use multiple if/else or a case statement which I cannot use with assign as far as I understand.

Now I have an issue that I have to have a reg on the LHS in the `always` block although it is combinatorial logic in this case and it will not infer a register in this case.

But if I change `CMD` to `reg` then I cannot use the {} notation to combine `CAS`, `RAS` and `WE`.

I could replace the `CMD` with a task or combine/split `CAS`, `RAS` and `WE` outside the module and have them as a single `CMD` module parameter.

Any more elegant way of expressing this?

Comment: Are you using Verilog or SystemVerilog? What you've show so far looks like very  Verilog. What is "LFS"? A typo for LHS? The code you have show so far is ilegal as you cannot procedurally assign "CMD"

Comment: Yes, LHS, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have have multiple variables that you would like to assign at once, you can use the concatenation operator on the LHS of an expression:

```
output logic CAS, RAS, WE;
...
logic [2:0] CMD;

assign {CAS, RAS, WE} = CMD;
...
CMD = 3'b011; // Will assign CAS = 0, RAS = 1, WE = 1
...
```

You can also just not use `CMD` at all and just use `{CAS, RAS, WE}` in its place; depending on your style and what makes sense for your project. A side note, ideally, you should be using `always_comb` over `always @(*)` and `logic` over `wire` and `reg` (mostly) if you are in a SystemVerilog environment as you seem to be.